# YAML Pull Request Security

Tags: azure-devops

When reading the documentation, it says that when doing a pull request, the "source" azure pipelines file is read when doing the PR check.

**How is this in any way secure?** Any developer that executes a pull request can now use the service connections the build might use and do whatever they want with it.

In other systems, it always uses the *target* branch CI configuration for pull requests. Is there any way to configure Azure Devops for this behavior?

What's the best practice here?

Comment: This is an issue of least-permissions. If a developer shouldn't be able to do something with a service connection, the service connection shouldn't be able to do it. If a developer shouldn't be using a service connection *at all*, then it should be restricted so that it can only be used in appropriate contexts. It doesn't make sense to use the build defined in the target branch as a CI build; there could be breaking changes in the source PR branch that necessitates changing the build. In that scenario, using the target branch's CI definition means you are guaranteed to have build failures.

Comment: @ Daniel Mann The scenario you gave is convincing. I think you can move your comment to the answer.